# Unpublished google play app

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have an android app that is ranking well in google play. The app has to communicate with a server and now I have to change my server. I am thinking to unpublish the app until the dns is modified (if not for a period of time, user will register to both servers). If I shut down the original server, then it is possible to get bad reviews(users can not register).

What are the consequences if you unpublish and then republish the application? Do you loose your ranking or other stats?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpublishing an application for only a day, doesn't affect your ranking.

I had an application unpublished for about 2 month and from almost first place, it was now down to about 50. I think this had to do with the uninstalls without any install

Comment: Will unpublishing an app permanently affect users that have the app installed? Will it continue to work for them (no updates, obviously)?